# Bx Slider adding massive width

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bxslider

I'm currently attempting to build a site using bootstrap. Everything is going well thus far until I come to plugin bx-slider into the page.

Currently its adding a width of `width: 999999px` when I inspect the element and as you can imagine its causing the layout to look awful. Images in the slider are of the same height and width.

Here is the html

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="bx-slider" class="span9">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/working-together.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            In libero ante, egestas non interdum sed, vestibulum ullamcorper dui. 
                            Nunc consectetur commodo quam, vel accumsan erat ultrices nec. 
                            Aenean dolor felis, tincidunt et ultricies vitae, mattis in ante. 
                            Phasellus dapibus pretium aliquam. 
                            Vestibulum vestibulum massa a enim facilisis volutpat. Class aptent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/discussion.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            In libero ante, egestas non interdum sed, vestibulum ullamcorper dui. 
                            Nunc consectetur commodo quam, vel accumsan erat ultrices nec. 
                            Aenean dolor felis, tincidunt et ultricies vitae, mattis in ante. 
                            Phasellus dapibus pretium aliquam. 
                            Vestibulum vestibulum massa a enim facilisis volutpat. Class aptent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/facilitator.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            In libero ante, egestas non interdum sed, vestibulum ullamcorper dui. 
                            Nunc consectetur commodo quam, vel accumsan erat ultrices nec. 
                            Aenean dolor felis, tincidunt et ultricies vitae, mattis in ante. 
                            Phasellus dapibus pretium aliquam. 
                            Vestibulum vestibulum massa a enim facilisis volutpat. Class aptent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/leadership.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            In libero ante, egestas non interdum sed, vestibulum ullamcorper dui. 
                            Nunc consectetur commodo quam, vel accumsan erat ultrices nec. 
                            Aenean dolor felis, tincidunt et ultricies vitae, mattis in ante. 
                            Phasellus dapibus pretium aliquam. 
                            Vestibulum vestibulum massa a enim facilisis volutpat. Class aptent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/success.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            In libero ante, egestas non interdum sed, vestibulum ullamcorper dui. 
                            Nunc consectetur commodo quam, vel accumsan erat ultrices nec. 
                            Aenean dolor felis, tincidunt et ultricies vitae, mattis in ante. 
                            Phasellus dapibus pretium aliquam. 
                            Vestibulum vestibulum massa a enim facilisis volutpat. Class aptent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/teamwork.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                            In libero ante, egestas non interdum sed, vestibulum ullamcorper dui. 
                            Nunc consectetur commodo quam, vel accumsan erat ultrices nec. 
                            Aenean dolor felis, tincidunt et ultricies vitae, mattis in ante. 
                            Phasellus dapibus pretium aliquam. 
                            Vestibulum vestibulum massa a enim facilisis volutpat. Class aptent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                    In libero ante, egestas non interdum sed, vestibulum ullamcorper dui. 
                    Nunc consectetur commodo quam, vel accumsan erat ultrices nec. 
                    Aenean dolor felis, tincidunt et ultricies vitae, mattis in ante. 
                    Phasellus dapibus pretium aliquam. 
                    Vestibulum vestibulum massa a enim facilisis volutpat. Class aptent.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the JS

```
$(function(){
$('#bx-slider').bxSlider ({
   minSlides: 1,
   maxSlides: 10,
   auto: true,
   pager: false,
   controls: false,
   autoDelay: 1000,
   autoHover: true,
   slideWidth: 770
});});
```

As you can see I have tried adding in slideWidth and max min slides as suggested on there website.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Just changed the slider to a un-ordered list and each slide to be a list element to no avail. The slider wrapper and window are picking up the width fine but its seems to add the width to the bx-slider element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer was to put a containing div around the bx slider with the span class attached to that so ending up like this.

```
<div class="span9">
    <ul id="bx-slider" class="slider-border">                      
       <li>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```